# Error while using confluent-kafka python library with AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to use the [confluent-kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) python library to administer my cluster via a lambda function but the function fails with the error:

```
"Unable to import module 'Test': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'"
```

My requirements.txt

```
requests
confluent-kafka
```

To create the zip file I moved my code to the site-packages location of the virtual env and zipped everything.

Python Code:

```
import confluent_kafka.admin
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello World")
```

I am using the macOS 10.X. On Linux, I noticed that pip install creates a separate confluent_kafka.libs which does not get created on mac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created the required layer and can **verity that it works**.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I verified it  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
echo requests > requirements.txt
echo confluent-kafka >> requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r mylayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import confluent_kafka.admin
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(dir(confluent_kafka.admin))
    print(dir(requests))
    print("Hello World")
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['AdminClient', 'BrokerMetadata', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_DYNAMIC_BROKER_CONFIG', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_DYNAMIC_DEFAULT_BROKER_CONFIG', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG', 'CONFIG_SOURCE_UNKNOWN_CONFIG', 'ClusterMetadata', 'ConfigEntry', 'ConfigResource', 'ConfigSource', 'Enum', 'KafkaException', 'NewPartitions', 'NewTopic', 'PartitionMetadata', 'RESOURCE_ANY', 'RESOURCE_BROKER', 'RESOURCE_GROUP', 'RESOURCE_TOPIC', 'RESOURCE_UNKNOWN', 'TopicMetadata', '_AdminClientImpl', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'concurrent', 'functools']
['ConnectTimeout', 'ConnectionError', 'DependencyWarning', 'FileModeWarning', 'HTTPError', 'NullHandler', 'PreparedRequest', 'ReadTimeout', 'Request', 'RequestException', 'RequestsDependencyWarning', 'Response', 'Session', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired', '__author__', '__author_email__', '__build__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__cake__', '__copyright__', '__description__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__', '__url__', '__version__', '_check_cryptography', '_internal_utils', 'adapters', 'api', 'auth', 'certs', 'chardet', 'check_compatibility', 'codes', 'compat', 'cookies', 'delete', 'exceptions', 'get', 'head', 'hooks', 'logging', 'models', 'options', 'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'session', 'sessions', 'ssl', 'status_codes', 'structures', 'urllib3', 'utils', 'warnings']
Hello World
```

Comment: It seems there is a difference in how wheel does the installation for confluent-kafka on macOS vs Linux. As I mentioned in the question, on Linux pip install creates a separate confluent_kafka.libs and because Lambda runs on Amazon Linux it was expecting a separate library. However, since I was creating the zip on mac it didn't have that. I was able to run the code when I used the virtual env from a linux box.

Comment: I have tried this, pip installed `confluent-kafka` using platform `linux/amd64` but it still gives me an import error. can you provide a little more guidance?

Answer (score 2):

I hit this even after setting up a layer properly.  I was able to work around this problem by setting my layer and function to use the architecture x86_64